# 2015 Toyota RAV4 service manual

Tags: toyota, rav4, service-manual

Can you buy a 2015 Toyota RAV4 service manual? The dealer has promised me one and it's been almost a month and no service manual.

Comment: I made the same deal with my Rav4. they even charged me 500 dollars. I got the "we owe you" slip. I waited the stated time and never got it. Had to chase the sales man down because he did not return any request for communication. Later , i did get my money back and found that service manuals are no longer made available . you have to pay for a level of access to their online service. while you can print the desired info, you cannot download the book. Corporations suck. They will never touch my car unless it absolutely cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy earlier ones from [Best Brands Repair Manuals](http://www.autorepairmanuals.biz/page/842533) and [Helm Inc](http://www.helminc.com/helm/welcome_select_oem.asp?Style=helm), but not yet for the 2015.

I'm surprised the dealership has told you they'd give you the service manuals. Are you sure they aren't offering you the *owner's manual*? They don't usually hand out service manuals. Also, a lot of the newer service manuals for dealerships actually come via electronic means (online or CD), so won't be available that way either. I don't know if Toyota does it this way or not.

Comment: When I brought the car one of my stipulations was a service manual. I was told it was on a Cd but have not received it yet and am very frustrated. I do fix my own cars and I don't know if it's possible to get the manual from somewhere else. Thanks for answering, if you have any advice please help!

Comment: @Bob - If you are in the US, did you get anything in writing stating as such? It would be something called a ***we owe*** slip. If you didn't get it in writing, don't expect to get your service manual. If you have a we owe slip, you'll need to go in and talk to the General Manager (not the salesperson). The we owe is a binding document which the dealership has to fulfill. If they don't, you can take them to court (if it ever gets that far) and the court can enforce the document. Usually, the dealership will have you sign one which says "we owe you nothing" to cover their own butts.